# Transform text effect

Tags: microsoft-publisher

Microsoft Word has this effect under
<kbd>Drawing Tools</kbd>
<kbd>WordArt Styles</kbd>
<kbd>Text Effects</kbd>
<kbd>Transform</kbd>

However when I use Publisher under
<kbd>Text box tools</kbd>
<kbd>WordArt Styles</kbd>
<kbd>Text Effects</kbd>

I only see these options

```
Shadow
Reflection
Glow
Bevel
```

How can I achieve the *Transform text effect* with Pubisher?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @techie007 updated